# USB-C Devices not being detected until I run `sudo lsusb -v`

Tags: linux, usb

I have a AMD 6800U based handheld.  It has 2 x USB-C ports.
Any USB type device I plug into either of these ports does not get "discovered" automatically.  I have found that the ONLY way to get them to discover USB devices connected is to run either `sudo lsusb -v` or `sudo cat /dev/bus/usb/009/001` (which is the root of the USB device).

I can see this by running `sudo dmesg -w`  plug in the USB-C device and I get no output,  as soon as I run either of the above, all the devices appear in the kernel logs.

Either of these cause the USB devices attached to the port to get discovered by the kernel.
I have never seen this behaviour on Linux before.  Any ideas what causes it?
I am running Arch with Kernel `6.3.9-arch1-1`.

EDIT: Added output from `dmesg -k -w` while booting with a USB-C SSD plugged in.
The device is 6-2. Of note, after unplugging it, I plugged it again (nothing) and unplugged it againl which also doesn't show up at all in the output.

[dmesg output](https://gist.github.com/Lord-Kamina/a9f5c34535434e626194147accd7b513)

Comment: that sounds like a kernel bug, possibly a regression. When you boot from a USB drive with a more conservative kernel (say, the Ubuntu 23.04 live USB image), does it work?

Comment: I just tested `6.1.35-1-lts` on the same hardware.  Has exactly the same behaviour.  This is not booting a live cd, I just installed the arch LTS kernel.

Comment: The intentionally different OS would help try other xinput/evdev/… configurations as well. But you could run `sudo evtest` to see whether that gives some insight!

Comment: I am having this exact same issue, began after force downgrading a 23.10 install back to 23.04, via apt pinning.

Of note, neither `lsusb`, nor `lsusb -v`nor `sudo lsusb` work. It has to be `sudo lsusb -v`

Comment: @GregorioLitenstein weird bug, do you have any hibernation/sleep option turned on?

Comment: I would suspect a difference in timeouts values. (boot time / lsusb). Ages ago lsusb was even capable to hang forever, waiting vs 500ms or so at boot time. Some adequate quirck should solve this issue.

Comment: @tukan Nope. Hibernation is off because of not enough HD; sleep is currently broken entirely (also looking into it but not a priority right now). Either way, this can happen with the computer just booted or a couple hours in, no difference.

Comment: @MC68020 Actually, I just realized I had not tested it during boot. I just noticed that if I boot with the device plugged in, it works fine. If having done that, I unplug the device and plug it back in in the same port, it doesn't work. Each time I plug it in, I have to run `sudo lsusb -v` for it to be detected.

Comment: @GregorioLitenstein could you show us what does the `dmesg` log show when you unplug it and plug it back after having it plugged in during the boot?

Comment: @tukan I accidentally also submitted as an edit to the post because I'm dumb. this is booting with a USB-C SSD plugged in. The device is 6-2. Of note, after unplugging it, I plugged it again (nothing) and unplugged it again, which also doesn't show up at all in the output. Here's the log: https://gist.github.com/Lord-Kamina/a9f5c34535434e626194147accd7b513

Answer (score -1):

If SELinux is on, relabeling can resolve unexplained behavior.

```shell
sudo restorecon -Rv /
```

Comment: Sorry but OP stated "Kernel 6.3.9-arch1-1" I just cannot see what SELinux would have to do in that stuff.